# How should a buddhist behave when he&she is treated unfairly?

Tags: reference-request, karma, yoga

OK, religions just say: "be patient, trust god and never think revenge!" god takes your revenge or better you will see prize here or you will reach nirvana I mean big paradise prize in other world if you behave like jesus crist or prophet youself.

I wonder if buddhism says the same things or something different?

(please do not mention just trust karma or make yoga things here, cos I did not see any winner before in my life) I and my family are suffering about our bad life experiences that caused by some bad people. Moreover these are legal so we cant do anything other than enduring but that we did not deserve..

Comment: Welcome to BuddhismSE. If you'd like to learn more about the site, please head over to the [help centre.](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help)

Answer (score 3):

When a tsunami destroys our house, there is hardship. And anger does not help.

When oppressive laws destroy our peace, there is hardship. And anger does not help.

Hardship opens the door to massive sorrow at the loss of kinder times. But anger and resentment only lead to different sorrows. The Buddha teaches us to kill our anger and give up resentment.

> [SN1.71:3.2](https://suttacentral.net/sn1.71/en/sujato#sn1.71:3.2): When anger’s incinerated there is no sorrow.
> [SN1.71:3.3](https://suttacentral.net/sn1.71/en/sujato#sn1.71:3.3): O deity, anger has a poisoned root
> [SN1.71:3.4](https://suttacentral.net/sn1.71/en/sujato#sn1.71:3.4): and a honey tip.
> [SN1.71:3.5](https://suttacentral.net/sn1.71/en/sujato#sn1.71:3.5): The noble ones praise its killing,
> [SN1.71:3.6](https://suttacentral.net/sn1.71/en/sujato#sn1.71:3.6): for when it’s incinerated there is no sorrow.”

But even giving up anger and resentment, hardship remains. And here the Buddha says we have four supports.

> [DN34:2.3.81](https://suttacentral.net/dn34/en/sujato#dn34:2.3.81): And how does a mendicant have four supports?
> [DN34:2.3.82](https://suttacentral.net/dn34/en/sujato#dn34:2.3.82): After appraisal, a mendicant uses some things, endures some things, avoids some things, and gets rid of some things.

So in the face of hardship, we use what we can, endure what we must, avoid additional hardships, and get rid of things such as anger and resentment.

After a tsunami, we might rebuild on higher ground.  And oppressive laws might be changed or left behind.

May you find peace for yourself and others in the hardships you face.

Comment: Anger is a very important motivation and antidote to dullness. I wonder if the Buddha had anything positive to say about anger as well.

Comment: @henning, The Buddha never said anything positive about it. Anger is just a poison which weakens discernment.

Comment: @danilo agreed. The Buddha discourages anger. Instead of anger, the Buddha encourages _rousing energy_ as an antidote to the dullness.

Answer (score 1):

Buddhism largely follows a similar format to the one you provided, but one is encouraged to 'figure things out for themselves' rather than blindly following a leader like a duckling follows its mother.

Encouraging this autonomy empowers a person to see in their own direct experience how they create their future circumstances.

> 5. "He abused me, he struck me, he overpowered me, he robbed me." Those
>    who harbor such thoughts do not still their hatred.
> 6. "He abused me, he struck me, he overpowered me, he robbed me." Those who do not harbor such thoughts still their hatred.

It is only amongst the quietude of the mind that one can then understand the brevity and scope of the pains we unconsciously cause ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is at the center of the Four Noble Truth.

1. Life is pain, no matter what you do. Birth is pain, death is pain, and sustaining our way of life is painful.
2. The cause of pain is attachment and expecatation from who you think you are or whom you expect to become.
3. Letting go of who you are or who you think you should be, is the way to getting rid of attachment and therefore pain.
4. For practicing the "letting go" of attachment to your life and persona, the Eightfold Path was created. Following the Eightfold Path is a way of life, helping with the 1-2-3s of the Four Noble Truths.

One strategy I use (in difficult situations) is that I turn it into a teaching, to show me where I still get stuck. How did I allow this situation to happen? Blaming myself first, before the mind can strategize about blaming someone else, puts the responsibility and therefore the solution in my hand. Giving the second part away to someone else just to avoid blame, robs you from the ability to change it.

Answer (score 0):

[Justice vs. Skillfulness](https://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/thanissaro/justicevsskill_en.html) might help good householder, if reading with proper attention.

And one would also have feets to walk on. Not all needs to be taken when there are skilful ways to step aside. Of course ill-will is an obstacle to go on, yet a wise would/could remove it from the exit path.

Knowing that what ever build up would get swept away, in this or that way: Why not seeking for an escape and an end of another rebuild and turn toward doing merits toward path?